# Stop all services for a backup of /var

Tags: services

I wrote a script for backing up `/etc`, `/home` and `/var` as `.tgz`-files and copying them on a windows disk in the network.
As I tested the script everything worked perfectly. But now I always get the error that some data changed during reading them.
All of the errors are on `/var` and I think they are all because some service is running. I changed the script, so it would stop the `apache2` and `mysql` services while packing the archives. But I still got the errors.

So my question is:

Is there a way to stop all services which are using `/var`?

I hope you can help me.
Have a nice day and thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is much of a point of backing up data that changes that often. It depends on what you want to use the backup for. If you need to e.g. restore a database, a simple `cp` with the server running is not going to work, but other means are available. As it stands, your question sounds like an [XY Problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341).

Comment: Well I think i was too lazy. Will change my script so it will only backup some dirs from /var. Thank you anyway.